# Breaking up a 2d shape into small triangles

Tags: 2d, javascript, tessellation

I have a "piece of cloth" (2d shape) that I'm applying soft-body physics to.  This works great when the shape is a square and I can create a regular grid of vertices between which are hung the cloth's "springs."  However, now I'm trying to get this to work with non-square piece of cloth, so I'd like to be able to break the polygon down into thousands of tiny triangles.  I've seen lots of libraries to tessellate or triangulate polygons, but they all seem to minimize the number of triangles created, which is exactly the opposite of what I want.

Does anyone know of a library (optimally in JS!) that breaks up a polygon into arbitrarily small chunks?  Preferably as regular as possible (i.e., creating a grid-like layout where possible), but not required.

Alternatively, does anyone know if there's a name for this, so I can just look up the algorithm and implement it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and it turns out that "polygon subdivision" is the search term for this, and three.js has a library for it: [SubdivisionModifer.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js).  It can be used as:

```
var modifier = new SubdivisionModifier(2);
modifier.modify(geometry);
```

Note that the first time I ran it I passed in 10 for the constructor and the tab at 1.5GB of memory and crashed: lower is better.

Comment: If you come back, don't forget to mark your answer as "Accepted" so it's easier for users with similar questions to find working solutions.